# Higher order component with generic inception types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I have got a generic union type for fetching data called `RemoteData` for which I tried to create a higher order component:

```js
export interface IWithRemote<T> {
  remote: RemoteData<T>;
}

export interface IWithData<T> {
  data: T;
}

export function withRemoteData<T, K extends IWithData<T>>(XComponent: React.ComponentType<K>) {
  return class extends React.Component<IWithRemote<T>> {
    render() {
      const { remote } = this.props;
      switch (remote.kind) {
        case RemoteDataKind.NotAsked:
          return <div> nice not asked yet </div>;
        case RemoteDataKind.Loading:
          return <Spinner />;
        case RemoteDataKind.Success:
          return <XComponent data={remote.data} />
        case RemoteDataKind.Failure:
          return <div>daaaamn</div>;

        default:
          return assertNever(remote);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

But these types do not work. Not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible, anyway I'm getting

> TS2322: Type '{ data: T; }' is not assignable to type 'K'.

When I try to assign `remote.data` to `data` of `XComponent`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-rur4g?fontsize=14) you find all of the code needed to reproduce the problem. Is there a way to fix these types?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```
export function withRemoteData<T>(
    XComponent: React.ComponentType<IWithData<T>>
) {
    return class extends React.Component<IWithRemote<T>> {
        render() {
            const { remote } = this.props;
            switch (remote.kind) {
                case RemoteDataKind.NotAsked:
                    return <div> nice not asked yet </div>;
                case RemoteDataKind.Loading:
                    return <div> spinnnnnner </div>;
                case RemoteDataKind.Success:
                    return <XComponent data={remote.data} />;
                case RemoteDataKind.Failure:
                    return <div>daaaamn</div>;

                default:
                    return assertNever(remote);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-38bnw

Comment: But this limits the component which can be passed to this HOC. If I pass any component with more that one prop `data`. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-qk3sp It cuts off other props.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter type for the HOC, `XComponent`, expects its properties to conform to some type `K`, which may contain some extra properties in addition to `data`.

But the `props` type for the HOC, `IWithRemote<T>`, has `remote` property which is declared to have only `data` when `kind` is `Success`, nothing else.

So, when you render `XComponent` with

```
<XComponent data={remote.data} />
```

Where are all the other properties in `K` that `XComponent` expects to receive for its `props` are supposed to come from?

Anyway, if everything that `XComponent` needs is coming together with `data` in `remote` when `kind` is `Success`, you can declare that it's indeed so - you just need to add that `K` parameter to `RemoteData` and `IWithRemote`, and declare `Success` union member as intersection type

```
   {
            kind: RemoteDataKind.Success;
      } & K
```

The complete types are

```
type RemoteData<T, K extends IWithData<T>> =
    | {
            kind: RemoteDataKind.NotAsked;
      }
    | {
            kind: RemoteDataKind.Loading;
      }
    | {
            kind: RemoteDataKind.Success;
      } & K
    | {
            kind: RemoteDataKind.Failure;
            error: Error;
      };

interface IWithRemote<T, K extends IWithData<T>> {
    remote: RemoteData<T, K>;
}

interface IWithData<T> {
    data: T;
}

export function withRemoteData<T, K extends IWithData<T>>(
    XComponent: React.ComponentType<K>
) {
    return class extends React.Component<IWithRemote<T, K>> {
```

Then when you render `XComponent` you need to make sure that everything that's in `remote` is passed to it, not just `data`:

```
            case RemoteDataKind.Success:
                return <XComponent {...remote} />;
```

Comment: It kind of worked... but it also takes all of the props of component passed to HOC from props to remote. You can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-txk9f `somethingElse`, becomes a property of `remote` in Success state, instead of being a prop.

Comment: "it also takes all of the props of component passed to HOC from props to remote" - I put them there because I don't know where else these properties can come from. Are any of them non-optional? Do you need any knowledge of the exact type of these properties inside the HOC? If the answer to these questions is "no", I don't think you even need `K` generic type parameter, you can simply use `XComponent: React.ComponentType<IWithData<T>>`